# Gitlab CI react-scripts: not found

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build a simple pipeline for a sample react project.
This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: node:12

stages:
  - build
  - test

build_react:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building deploy package"
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
    - echo "Build successful"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build

test_react:
  stage: test
  needs: [build_react]
  script:
    - echo "Testing project"
    - yarn test --watchAll=false
    - echo "Test successful"
```

The build passed, but on testing stage it failed complaining about

```
 $ react-scripts test --watchAll=false
 /bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the problem comes from `build_react`:
Command `yarn install` will install the dependencies in the **`node_modules`** folder (This folder is not in the repository's committed files since it is mentioned in `.gitignore`).
If you need the dependencies in other dependent jobs (`test_react` in your case), they should be specified as `cache` or `artifacts`.
Thus, `build_react` might look like this:

```
⋮

build_react:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building deploy package"
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
    - echo "Build successful"
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build
      - node_modules/    ### This will make the modules available to other dependent jobs

⋮
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Made my day... Searched for about 3 days on this one! Thanks!